# Get the coordinates when the Pegman is dropped.

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

How can I get the co-ordinates of the location where the Pegman is dropped? Couldn't find any helpful articles here in Stackoverflow and in Google API. Is there any event that can be captured on Pegman drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the map try with  a listener on the click event

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(map,    'click',    function(event){
                alert(event.latLng );
            });
```

for streetview look at this google [sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-events) 
*(below you see the concept  but for a complete the sample is better)*

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'position_changed', function() {
     alert(panorama.getPosition()) ;
 });
```

Comment: It works for the maps. But not in the streetview. Any idea?

Comment: I do not understand your comment above. The map coordinates are right? and what you are looking for. If you can explain better what you need

Comment: Sorry if my previous comment didn't make any sense. I'm trying to get the location of the place where the Pegman isd dropped. If I click on the map (not the streetview which we get after placing the Pegman) I get the locaiton as alert. But when I click on the streetview and change the position, I'm not able to get the location.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle? Seems not working at my end.

Comment: I have update the answer with a link to a complete sample provided by google.. i hope this is useful for you and you can rate me.

Comment: I already have this link and tried this. I think you still didn't get what I'm looking for. When the page loads, I need a google map (not streetview). and then the user should be able to drop the pegman inside the map and get the location in the streetview (even when he change the position by dragging the streetview).

Comment: I'sorry but with the first sample provide by me you get the coordinates by map and then with reverse geocode you can get the location, with the second sample provided by google you get the position (coordinates) moving on streetview. with this position you can obtain the position with reverse geocode again.

Comment: Can you make an `alert(event.latLng)` on this map: http://jsfiddle.net/22zrhr92/   after dropping the pegman on the map?

Comment: As it is obviously not. For the map you have the object map, but you do not have the object streetview "panorama". and so if you want the functionality you are looking for you have to create a window on which you can capture your streetview events.

Comment: The streetview will be replaced by the google maps when you drop a Pegman. And it is really hard to get a `position_changed` event on that streetview. This event will only be helpful when we define the panorama object just like the map object.